# Broken pipe error - description with solution

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, pipe

This is a problem I'd like to share with everyone. Also - I have resolved it and it was a pretty interesting problem.

When I received my laptop from repair I had my OS reinstalled. Everything (I mean whole configuration and programming environment) I had to do once more time from scratch.
It took some time, but the next day I was able to return to my work.

Problems started when I tried to run my Java - Spring App. I could run it, but immediately I was facing an error. Within the console, I have read that it was called a broken pipe error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this error was to rename the account name in the registry. My account name was using special characters (f.e. like Ü).

I have created a second user with the role of admin. Later I have used win + r, typed regedit, and fired it.

When the Registry Editor has opened, I've entered HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList and in there I've found an account of mine. After that, I have changed ProfileImagePath for the desired name.

In the end, I have changed the name of the folder %SystemDrive%\Documents and Settings<Your_Name_To_Change> for the same I have used in the registry. It has solved my problem with broken pipe error.